# What are the roles of ${$exp}, $-[$exp], and $+[$exp] in this Perl example which extracts the locations where a regular expression matches?

Tags: regex, perl

What is the meaning of `$#- and $-[$exp]`

```
$x = "Mmm...donut, thought Homer";

$x =~ /^(Mmm|Yech)\.\.\.(donut|peas)/; # matches

foreach $exp (1..$#-)
{
    print "Match $exp: '${$exp}' at position ($-[$exp],$+[$exp])\n";
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Match 1: 'Mmm' at position (0,3)
Match 2: 'donut' at position (6,11)
```

Comment: Check http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40-

Comment: When your titles start with "Explain", "Decode" etc they give the appearance of orders rather than thoughtful questions. The rapidity with which you ask questions which demonstrate no understanding make your questions look more than a bit shady. Like, maybe, you are asking them during a test.

Comment: hey @SinanÜnür i dont understand why is it sounding like an order to u ...and let me assure you i m not in the middle of test ..this is a code from perldoc.perl.org.

Comment: That's how you order people around in English: "Do this", "do that", "do the other thing" etc ... I am going to edit your question this time so you can emulate the style in your future posts.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, `$#ary` is the index of the last element of the array `@ary`. Therefore, `$#-` is the index of the last element of the array [`@-`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#LAST_MATCH_START):

> `$-[0]` is the offset of the start of the last successful match. `$-[n]` is the offset of the start of the substring matched by n-th subpattern, or undef if the subpattern did not match.

Therefore, `1 .. $#-` is a range of indices into `@-`.

`${$exp}` is a symbolic dereference. If `$exp` is one, you get the text of `$1`. I would not use this in real code. Instead, use `@+` to extract the substring.

Also, while you know this example is going to match, in real life, ***never*** use the digit variables without ensuring the previous match succeeded.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = "Mmm...donut, thought Homer";

if ( $x =~ /^(Mmm|Yech) [.]{3} (donut|peas)/x ) {
    for my $i (1 .. $#-) {
        my ($s, $e) = ($-[$i], $+[$i]);
        printf(
            "Match %d: '%s' at position [%d,%d)\n",
            $i, substr($x, $s, $e - $s), $s, $e
        );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Match 1: 'Mmm' at position [0,3)
Match 2: 'donut' at position [6,11)
```

Note that:

> `$+[1]` is the offset past where `$1` ends, `$+[2]` the offset past where `$2` ends, and so on. You can use `$#+` to determine how many subgroups were in the last successful match.

Hence, the abuse of the half-closed interval notation above.